# RushORM database throwing Excretion while getting data

Tags: android, database, sqlite, rushorm, constructor-exception

I am using `RushORM` database in my `Android` App. I can save data but when I try to get the stored data it is throwing an exception:

> Method threw `RushTableMissingEmptyConstructorException`.

Here is the model class that is table `RushORM` database:

```
public class Linesmodel extends RushObject {
    float startX, startY, stopX, stopY;
    String cityName;
    float joinX, joinY = 0;

    Linesmodel(float startX, float startY, float stopX, float stopY) {
        this.startX = startX;
        this.startY = startY;
        this.stopX = stopX;
        this.stopY = stopY;
    }

    Linesmodel(String cityname, float startX, float startY, float stopX, float stopY) {
        this.startX = startX;
        this.startY = startY;
        this.stopX = stopX;
        this.stopY = stopY;
        this.cityName = cityname;
    }

    Linesmodel(float startX, float startY) { // for convenience
        this(startX, startY, startX, startY);
    }
}
```

Here is the code by which I am saving data:

```
for (Linesmodel l : lines) {
    new Linesmodel(selectedCity, l.startX, l.startY, l.stopX, l.stopY).save();
}
```

Here is the code that fetches the data. The exception is thrown on this code:

```
List<Linesmodel> linesList = new RushSearch().find(Linesmodel.class);
```

Comment: Throwing excretion? You might want to edit that title...

Comment: Yes, throwing an exception. can you please suggest me batter relateable Title.

Answer (score 0):

RushOrm uses reflection to populate the properties and therefore needs an empty constructor.

Just add this constructor and you should be good

```
Linesmodel() {}
```

Also on an unrelated note you might want to try saving your list using

```
RushCore.getInstance().save(objects)
```

Does the same just faster, although you will only really notice the differences at 100+ objects.